# automorphism group of graph be doubly-transitive

Tags: graph-theory, automorphism-group

If $\Gamma$ is a graph of $n$ vertices.
Can the automorphism group of graph $\Gamma$ be doubly-transitive on the vertices of the graph?

Comment: Isn't $\Gamma = K_n$ an example?

Comment: What do you mean by $K_n$? and then can we find all such $\Gamma$ and their automorphism groups?

Comment: $K_n$ is the complete graph on $n$ vertices.  Is your question is to find all graphs with doubly-transitive automorphism groups?  Then it should say so.  Right now, it just asks if such a thing is possible.